# Displaying content according to the OG membership of the creator

Tags: 7, organic-groups, views, media

In our Drupal 7 site, we are using Organic Groups to create private groups. Users are also able to upload content to a gallery (using custom Content Types "Gallery image" and "Gallery video"). On users' profile pages, we are showing a carousel of their *N* most-recent uploads, with a View using a Contextual Filter on Author `uid`.

We would like to add a similar carousel to each OG group page, showing the most-recent *N* uploads by members of the group. [**Edit:** This is uploads to the general Gallery, the OG groups do not have their own galleries.] If it makes a difference, almost all users will be members of more than one group (for reasons that are unimportant, there are two kinds of group: geographic groups and interest-based groups).

This seems like it's probably very easy, but I just can't see how to do this, either from the View's *Contextual Filters* or the View's *Relationships*.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: For clarification: do you want to show "group content" from member who belong to the current group or do you want to show "any content" from members who belong to the current group? Btw, checkout this awesome OG tutorial: http://modulesunraveled.com/organic-groups.

Comment: The latter. Galleries are unrelated to the OG groups, but all users will be in at least two groups. User pages have a carousel that shows the most recent _N_ uploads from that user, we would like to add a carousel to the OG group pages that show the most recent _N_ uploads from "users who are members of this group". I've edited the question to make that [slightly] clearer. Thanks for the tutorial link; I'll go take a look in a moment.

Comment: this is a view that will show group content uploaded by  members of the group: http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/1360583?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1327942737&Signature=e4v4DUVhpMu3xiSLxVodL76BsGQ%3D. If you remove the "Group membership: Node group membership" relationship it might show all content by members of the group.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 6 you would add a relationship to the Organic Group: node then filter by Organic Group: user and use the relationship. I believe it should be something very similar by using the contextual filters...

Comment: Thanks; that gives me somewhere to start looking, at least :o)